# How to set value for each element in array with element in another array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Can I set values for each element in array with element from another array in ruby on rails ??:
Here my example:

```
ids = [1234,5678,....]
@fb = [](array)
@fb[0] = @graph.get_connections("#{ids[0](1234)}","?fields=posts)
@fb[1] = @graph.get_connections("#{ids[1](5678)}","?fields=posts)
```

Can i do that in ruby on rails, and how can i do ?? please! help me

I try to do this:

```
ids = [1234,5678,....]
ids.each do |id|
@fb = @graph.get_connections("#{id}","?fields=posts)
```

I think my @fb will get value with 2 id 1234 and 5678 but it just get value with one id:1234, So I want to set value for @fb with each id 1234 and 5678.

Comment: Please paste correctly syntaxed code, and give more explanation. There are too much room for guessing in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out **[Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)**.

```
ids = [ 123, 456 ]
connections = ids.map do |id|
  @graph.get_connections("#{ id }","?fields=posts")
end
```

Comment: :)  You know, I somehow assumed he already had an array @fb that he was adding or replacing values in.  Map is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?  Let's count down to zero starting with the size of the ids array minus 1.  At some point you really ought to guarantee that the arrays are the same size (or that @fb is larger).

```
(ids.count - 1).downto(0) { |i| @fb[i] = @graph.get_connections("#{ids[i]}", "?fields=posts") }
```